# xml file reader shows no errors but says there is an error

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, filereader

My XML file reader code shows no errors at all. But when I run the code then says there's an error where I have put in `//Line 5` not sure what exactly is wrong with it but it was working perfectly fine before.

```
    try
    {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        StaxParser read = new StaxParser();
        List<Fridgelogdata> readfridgelogdata = read.readFridgelogdata(file.getAbsolutePath()); //line5
        for (Fridgelogdata fridgelogdata : readfridgelogdata) {
            textArea.append(fridgelogdata+"\n\n");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        textArea.append("\n Error try again");
    }
} else {
    textArea.setText("user cancelled open command");
}

}
});
```

Comment: What is the error? How can anyone help, if they don't know what is the error! Please post the error stack trace

Comment: what is the error it gives?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post, too - it's hard to read at the moment. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I have a null pointer exception on the line that is commented out. I have created an object from a stax parser class called read. I then created a list in this GUI class, and I am setting it equal to the list in the parser class that contains the list of xml data. It worked before, but for some reason it has started throwing me a null pointer.

Comment: Sounds like `file` is null. Can you debug that code and set a breakpoint in line 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is null. You have created the file in the try block and your file chooser else where. So you have said like file = fc.getSelctedFile(), but fc is not declared in the same place, so your file is coming out null. You need to create your file with the file chooser. So

`fc = new JFileChooser();` 
`File file;`

```
try
{
   file = fc.getSelectedFile();`
}
catch ....
```

Next time, post the specific error and more code, like, you referenced fc in the code you posted but we don't know where it was delcared and such. :P